# Lint staged + ESLint are testing all files instead of staged

Tags: typescript, git, eslint, husky, lint-staged

I want to test my code on the `pre-commit` hook. To achieve it I installed `husky`, and `list-staged`.

Here's the config:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "test": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx ./**/*",
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.(ts|tsx)": [
      "npm run test"
    ]
```

So, in the theory, I can do something like:

```
git add file.ts
git commit -m commit
```

And *ESLint* will automatically check only `file.ts`. But actually it shows all the exceptions during `pre-commit`. Even if `file.ts` is the only file that staged, *ESLint* checks everything.

What is the problem?

Comment: What that configuration says is "before the commit is made, if any TS or TSX files have changed, run the test script, which lints (not the usual meaning of 'test') all of the files". If you want to reuse an NPM script, you at least need to add `--` to the end so the extra arguments lint-staged adds go to the script, not NPM itself: https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#reuse-npm-script

Comment: Oh, I got it, thank you. Now I use `"*.(ts|tsx)": ["eslint"]`